# Atom Editor, change color of function call

Tags: atom-editor

currently I am trying to "hack" my Atom-editor and I am stuck here: I want to change the color of whenever I call a function in python - just like it is in the basic setup of SublimeText3. I am using the following code in my styles.less:

```
    atom-text-editor::shadow {
      .meta.function-call.python {
         color: red;
      }
    }
```

The Problem is that this code also changes the color of all instances & modules to red leaving me with this mess here: [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss5Xj.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--meta.syntax--function-call.syntax--generic {
    color: #66D9EF;
  }
}
```

This works for me using magicpython. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2bST.png)

Comment: Thanks @Julius it worked! For everyone else having the same problem: Don't forget to disable language-Python if you install MagicPython!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
atom-text-editor .syntax--function-call {
    color: red;
}
```

Edit: Fixed as per first comment.

Comment: no, same problem as before. 
btw: yours should say atom-text-editor instead of atom-text editor.

Comment: You're right about the missing hyphen in my snippet, can you try adding a similar one, changing function-call to variable and red to yellow?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Nothing is marked in the color - this case yellow - then.

Comment: Can you place your cursor inside "games", and launch the editor:LogCursorScope command from Command Palette?

Comment: You should now know how to continue from there. Youcan also fire the developer tools and use the inspect to locate the correct classes to style.

Comment: Then try usging atom-text-editor .syntax--function-call:not(.arguments) as selector.

Comment: same result as in my question.